# How can I redirect the output of a command that only writes to a file, not stdio?

Tags: linux, command-line, bash, zsh, redirection

There’s a command I want to run that writes to a specified file. Is it possible to redirect the output of this command to the stdin of another command?

The command looks like this:

```
foo -o filename
```

I’ve tried this:

```
foo -o /dev/stdout | bar
```

But it says that it failed to open the file, I imagine because stdout is already being used.

Is there a way to accomplish what I’m looking to do?

Comment: would the `tail` command work here for you?  That is the first thing that comes to my mind.  I get what you are asking I think.. but perhaps it's is easier to `tail` the file from the first command which can redirect that file to stdout.  You should then be able to redirect that output to another process I think.

Comment: Either `foo` is poorly designed, or there's a reason it refuses to write to a pipe. The reason may be it needs the file to be seekable. *If this is really the case* then there is no simple way to make it work with a non-seekable file. Any workaround (like `tail`) may not work because the file can be modified at any "random" offset, not only by appending data to the end. Please [edit] and provide [MCVE](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366988/10765659). What exactly is `foo`?

Comment: Change `foo -o filename ...`  to `foo -o - ...`, that works for many utilities, might be for this one too.

Comment: Specifically I am trying to pipe the output of the macOS `say` command to `ffmpeg`. `say` with the `-o` flag can output an aiff file, and I would rather have an m4a file.

Is there a way to use `tail` in one command, perhaps with a temporary file? The following two commands worked for, but if I could have one command that'd be most excellent:

`tail -F temp.aiff | ffmpeg -i - out.m4a` followed by (in a second shell) `say "text" -o temp.aiff`.

Comment: Though maybe `say` does need the file to be seekable after all, it just failed with a larger file I tried to have it read.

Comment: Comments are not for addenda. Please [edit] the question and add your clarification to the question body.

Comment: The [basic specification of AIFF](http://www-mmsp.ece.mcgill.ca/Documents/AudioFormats/AIFF/Docs/AIFF-1.3.pdf) makes me suspect the program needs to generate all the data and only then it can fill in the `ckSize` chunk of `FORM AIFF`, which is *at the very beginning of the file*. The only way for `say` to pipe the file would be to buffer it as a seekable asset and start piping after all writing is done. This is against the whole idea of piping. Implementing this makes no sense because the overall result would be exactly like writing to a regular file and reading the file after `say` exits.

Comment: `say` appears to support m4a output directly (although maybe not for all voices). The [man page](https://www.unix.com/man-page/osx/1/say/) gives `y -o hi.m4a --data-format=alac Hello, World.` as an example.

Comment: Yeah, `say` can write m4a files, it's just not clear what voices support it directly.